# ubuntu - permission denied after make

Tags: linux, makefile, ubuntu-12.04

i like to run libsvm on my ubuntu client. I downloaded the files and run "make" but if i run ./svm-scale i got a permission denied.

I am new to linux/ubuntu how can i set the permissions?

This is the Makefile

```
CXX ?= g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -fPIC
SHVER = 1

all: svm-train svm-predict svm-scale

lib: svm.o
    $(CXX) -shared svm.o -o libsvm.so.$(SHVER)

svm-predict: svm-predict.c svm.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-predict.c svm.o -o svm-predict -lm
svm-train: svm-train.c svm.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-train.c svm.o -o svm-train -lm
svm-scale: svm-scale.c
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-scale.c -o svm-scale
svm.o: svm.cpp svm.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c svm.cpp
clean:
    rm -f *~ svm.o svm-train svm-predict svm-scale
```

if i run it with sudo i get command not found.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is:

$chmod -v u+x svm-train svm-predict svm-scale

BR

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a simple permissions problem, unless there's more going on here than described in the original post.  The linker will always generate executable files that have execute permissions, so running `make` followed by `./svm-scale` should not give permissions errors.

Are you sure the `make` step completed without any errors?

If you run `ls -l svm-scale` what does it say?  If you run `file svm-scale` what does it say?  If you run `umask` what does it say?  Maybe your umask is set to remove execute permissions (that would be *really* odd).

It's best if you cut and paste the exact commands you typed and the error message you got, rather than paraphrasing.

You shouldn't, and shouldn't need to, run using `sudo`.

Comment: if i "make" again, i got "make: nothing done for "all". ls -l svm-scale give me "-rw-rw-r-- 1 bitnami bitnami 16862 May 10 14:33 svm-scale", file svm-scale give me "svm-scale: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0x56e7c5cba12aff6b346b3842bf20ec095f7fa7f, not stripped"